# Center align checkbox in ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, alignment, center

I'm trying to center align a checkbox in a ListView row.

Each ListView row comprises of a checkbox (left aligned) and two rows of text (to the right of the checkbox).

Any ideas on how I center the checkbox inside the row i.e. center between top and bottom dividers as opposed to top row of text?

My ListView layout is below for reference.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
 >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbBoxSL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleX="1.4"
    android:scaleY="1.4"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

     >
</CheckBox>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSLItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbBoxSL"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cbBoxSL"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/aqua"
    android:singleLine="true">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_dateAdded"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSLItemName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="added on"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="@color/mid_grey"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cbBoxSL"
    >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSLItemName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_dateAdded"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/mid_grey"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_dateAdded"
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your checkbox XML.

`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Comment: Worked a charm..how I missed this one I'll never know!

Answer (score 1):

try to add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` or/and         `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in checkbox layout